# How to call a Java Method in a JSP page using JQUERY?

Tags: java, jquery, jsp

Lets say I created this method in a `JSP` page.

```
<%!
   String testMethod(String testString) {
       return testString;
   }
%>
```

And when I want to call this method, it will be like this.

```
<% out.println(testMethod("test")); %>
```

If I call it normally, it will be inside a `DIV`.

```
<div id="testDiv">
     <% out.println(testMethod("test")); %>
</div>
```

Now let's say, that this DIV exists, but its empty, and I want to call that method I created when I click on another element.

```
$("#testClick").click(function(){

});
```

`Append` won't work, since it simply appends the string, means it wont interpret `<% out.println(testMethod("test")); %>` as Java Code, it will append it as a normal String, how can I call this Java Code or Method, when I click on another element?

Comment: You cant. Java methods in jsp are interpreted on the server side, and jquery is on the client side.

Comment: There appears to be two separate but related questions here - (1) How do I call a server-side script from a click event handler and handle the response? (2) How do I write the sever-side script?

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot using $.get() I know it, but my real method is much bigger than this, I need to get many rows from a table in database, with many columns, and I send back 1 String (responseText), that contains all these stuff, then I count character by character to separate the data of each row and each column, so this is actually a bad approach (I suppose).

Comment: You have two main options (a) compose an HTML fragment server-side and return it, (b) compose a java array/object containing the row data and return a json-encoded representation of it. (a) is probably easier as the response can be inserted/appended into the DOM directly. With (b) you need to loop through the response client-side, compose HTML or DOM nodes from the data, then insert/append it/them into the DOM.

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot for (a), do you for example, $("#something").load("test.jsp"); ?

Comment: Yes, `$("#something").load("test.jsp");` is one way, and probably fits your needs. `$.ajax({...})` is the generalized method.

Comment: @AliBassam The question does not reflect what you want to achieve, if possible can you please update the question, by taking points from the comments. This will help others to answer your question more readily. Thanks